# Ability to use volume profile in trading strategy

Tags: pine-script

I would like to know if it is possible/or on the road map to be able to use the paid-for volume profile indicators data in a trading strategy - currently, I see no way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible in Pine. It might be added in the future, but not sure if and when.